# django-taggit obtain tags string from form

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-taggit

I trying to use django-taggit as a tag model.

model.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_no = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ... 
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def action(request):
    product = Product()

    user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    product.seller_username = user
    ...

    product.save()

    tag_list = taggit.utils._parse_tags(request.POST['tags'])
    product.tags.add(*tag_list)
```

When I call method product.tags.add(), I'm getting an error say

> Product objects need to have a primary key value before you can access
>   their tags

Many solutions I find inform me to put product.save() before product.tags.add() to make pk available before access many-to-many field.
I've try it and still the error.

Note: the save() method work properly. It create new object in Product list and can be see in admin interface.

Comment: Are you setting a value for `product.product_no` before saving it?

Comment: I don't set it, but because it is pk field, it should set automatically by save() method isn't it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem that I have to change

```
product_no = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

to

```
product_no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

and it's fixed.